# How To Distinguish Between Terraform Users In Container World?

Tags: docker, terraform

Based on my tests, it seems that Terraform records who locked the state file with `user@hostname`.  We are switching to running Terraform in containers.  This means every person will show up as the same user.  For example, if in our Dockerfile we define the user `myuser`, then everyone who runs Terraform via their corresponding container will show up as `myuser@containerhostname`.  If that’s the case we won’t know who has a lock on the statefile.

Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: This is not using TF Cloud or Enterprise?

Comment: No we're just using the open source Terraform product.  We built a Docker Image that uses it and now are asking all of our users to use that Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this becomes a question of how to run a Docker container as a host user because I don't see a way to configure this as a setting in Terraform.  So, my solution is to provide a wrapper script for users to run that runs the container as their host user.

Example excerpt:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
#if machine is Linux then passwdLocation=/etc/passwd 

if [ "$machine" = "Mac" ]; then
    echo "$USER:x:$(id -u):$(id -g):HostUser,,,:$HOME:/bin/bash" > /tmp/mac_passwd
    passwdLocation="/tmp/mac_passwd"
fi

docker run \
  --user=$(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -v $passwdLocation:/etc/passwd:ro \
  ...
```